# How to create textbox at run time and take values from these text box ? in C# . Net

Tags: c#, .net

I need your help in making text box at run time and taking values from these text boxes that user enter. i have two button and one rich_text_box , when user click on one button it creates 3 text boxes and then user click on other button it should take value from text boxes and how in rich text box .

this is code i am using to create dynamic textbox

```
private void create_textbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            TextBox text = new TextBox();
            text.Name = "Text Box" + i.ToString();
            //text.Text = "Text Box " + i.ToString();
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(text);


        }
    }
```

and this code i am using to take values from new created text boxes and displaying in rich text box .

```
private void get_value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     TextBox text = new TextBox();
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            string value = text.Text + i.ToString();
            richTextBox1.SelectedText  = "\r\n" + value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: So... what's your problem? What's wrong with your code? What's not happening that you want to happen?

Comment: Jup. Whats the problem? Is there an error?

Comment: Are text boxes the only control you have on 'flowLayoutPanel1'? You could iterate the controls collection and cast each control as a text box and get the value that way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private void get_value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            string value = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls["Text Box" + i].Text;
            richTextBox1.SelectedText  = "\r\n" + value;
        }
    }
```

This ought to do it.

Comment: this works for me thank you very very much :) , can you tell me any book to learn c# .net and work like pro ? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
private void get_value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (var c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
  {
    var t = c as TextBox;
    if (t != null)
    {
      richTextBox1.SelectedText  = "\r\n" + t.Text;
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method get_value_Click you aren't using any of the text boxes that were added to the flow layout panel. Something similar to Wolfgang Ziegler's answer should work but you will need to check the Type and Name in case you have other controls in the flow layout panel.